# Do I need to remove this movieClip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

In as2.0, I created a movie clip named "A" in the root with the function attachMovie. Then I attached a movieClip "B" in the mc "A". After removing the movieClip "A", do I need to remove "B"

Comment: Did you even try this out? It would take like 3 minutes tops to check if B remains on the stage or not after its parent has been removed...

Comment: no (removing the parent means automatically removing it's children, it's just how hierarchies work)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't. But if clip A or B uses some event handling you should unsubscribe both clips. And if you want to free memory you should clean all references to these clips so garbage collector can wipe them out.